# How capture destroy event in kendo ui grids when click is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to execute an action when click event of a delete button in a grid is done. How can I know when is clicked in Javascript?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(Read **IMPORTANT** at the end)

Use:

```
$("tr .k-grid-delete", "#grid").on("click", function(e) {
    alert("deleted pressed!");
})
```

Where `#grid` is the id of your grid.

If you want to know the data item you can do:

```
var item = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
```

Alternatively, you can define the `command` in the `grid.columns` as:

```
{
    command: [
        "edit",
        {
            name : "destroy",
            text : "remove",
            click: myFunction
        }
    ],
    title  : "Commands",
    width  : "210px" 
}
```

where `myFunction` is:

```
function myFunction(e) {
    alert("deleted pressed!");
    var item = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
    // item contains the item corresponding to clicked row
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** You might want to define you own `destroy` button where only the styling is copied from the original one (no other actions / checks). If so define your `grid.columns.command` as:

```
{
    command: [
        "edit",
        {
            name     : "destroy",
            text     : "remove",
            className: "ob-delete"
        }
    ],
    title  : "&nbsp;",
    width  : "210px"
}
```

and then define:

```
$(document).on("click", "#grid tbody tr .ob-delete", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("deleted pressed!");
    var item = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
    // item contains the item corresponding to clicked row
    ...
    // If I want to remove the row...
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").removeRow($(this).closest("tr"));
});
```

Comment: How can I get the data of row to delete of database when click event is done?

Comment: It does! Which version of Kendo UI are you using?

Comment: I am using v2012.3.1315. In `grid.columns` I have `{ command: "destroy", title: " ", width: "110px" }`, If I add your code: `[
        "edit",
        {
            name : "destroy",
            text : "remove",
            click: myFunction
        }
    ]`  It doesn't work

Comment: Yes. It is an array of buttons. In the example i put an edit and a destroy.

Comment: How can I remove only one row?

Comment: Only works with jQuery +1.83 and not with v2012.3.1315 which I use. I could use v2012.3.1114 of kendoui

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/8Nq8X/1/) with jQuery 1.7.2 and KendoUI v2012.3.1114. But it is true that it doesn't work with v2012.3.1315. Let me see if I can make my fiddle work with v2012.3.1315

Comment: Ok! Here (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/8Nq8X/4/) working with v2012.3.1315 and jQuery 1.83. I have had to change how `live` events are set up. Here (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/8Nq8X/3/) the same with jQuery 1.72.

Comment: Do you know why the remove functionallity doesn't work on mobile devices? sometimes works but not always

Comment: Hello. I contact you because I have a question about your example. If I add a grid content with backbone.js (a framework to make Single Page applications), the click event doesn't work on mobile devices. Do you know why? [the example ](http://jsfiddle.net/vicenrele/Thxtr/48/)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. It's my Android version. But I have another question about your example: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892406/reloading-kendo-ui-grid-the-row-item-code-executes-an-error). Regards

Answer (score 10):

simple. You can make use of `remove:` to capture destroy event in kendo.

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
        dataSource: gridDataSource,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        toolbar: ['create'],
        columns: [
            { field: 'id', title: 'ID', width: 'auto' },
            { field: 'description', title: 'Description', width: 'auto' },
            { field: 'begin', title: 'Begin', width: 'auto', format: '{0:d}' },
            { command: ['edit', 'destroy'], title: '&nbsp;', width: '172px' }
        ],
        editable: {
            mode: 'inline',
            confirmation: false
        },
        save:function(e){
          alert("save event captured");
          //Do your logic here before save the record.
        },       
        remove:function(e){ 
          alert("delete event captured");
          //Do your logic here before delete the record.
        }
    });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [
            { id: 1, description: 'Test 1', begin: new Date() }
        ],
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: 'id',
                fields: {
                    id: { type: 'number' },
                    description: { type: 'string' },
                    begin: { type: 'date' }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $('#grid').kendoGrid({
        dataSource: gridDataSource,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        toolbar: ['create'],
        columns: [
            { field: 'id', title: 'ID', width: 'auto' },
            { field: 'description', title: 'Description', width: 'auto' },
            { field: 'begin', title: 'Begin', width: 'auto', format: '{0:d}' },
            { command: ['edit', 'destroy'], title: '&nbsp;', width: '172px' }
        ],
        editable: {
            mode: 'inline',
            confirmation: false
        },
        save:function(e){
          alert("save event captured");
        },       
        remove:function(e){
          alert("delete event captured");
        }
    });
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid"></div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you need to recover the deleted row, use this: $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").cancelChanges();