# Reloading kendo ui grid the row item code executes an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've a web application with kendo ui grid. The grid is load with Bakbone.js when I click a button and I can remove a row with the next code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#grid tbody tr .ob-delete", function (e) {
    var item = grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
    var check = confirm("Do I delete:" + item.City );
    if (check) {
        grid.removeRow($(this).closest("tr"));
    }
});
```

The cofiguration of the button to delete:

```
 command: [
            "edit", {
            name: "destroy",
            text: "Remove",
            className: "ob-delete"
        }]
```

When I reload the content (grid) pushing the button, if I want to delete a row, `item.City` produce an error.

The complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Thxtr/49/)

Edited:
Solved [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vicenrele/Lu9Qf/18/)! Thanks to @Whizkid747!

To add in

```
command: [ "edit",{ 
      //...
      click: deleteRow
}]
```

Then, when button is clicked a function is called:

```
function deleteRow(e){
        var item = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
         var check = confirm("Do I delete:" + item.City );
        if (check) {
            grid.removeRow($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but your grid is actually not the same grid but the old (before the reload) one and second grid is created.

Following line changed:

```
var item = $('#grid').data().kendoGrid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
```

[updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu9Qf/).

I suggest you to just change the data through the [dataSource.data()](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#data) method instead of recreating the Grid. Or change your logic so you actually **[destroy](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/widget#destroy)** the widget before recreating it.

Comment: It seems solved but adding more content, It repeats the confirm multiple times. The example with another button [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu9Qf/2/)

Comment: Can you update the grid delete code with the one mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823072/a-button-in-a-kendo-ui-grid-doesnt-work-on-mobile-device/14917592#comment20939783_14917592) . if its still not working, i will take a look at it.